# Code generation

Tags: compiler-construction, code-generation

How does a compiler generate binary code to a separate file?
A reference to what file(s) in the source code of GCC handle this would be of great help. 
What I want to know is how exactly do compilers (gcc in particular) generate machine code from ASM?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please provide an example to stimulate thinking. :)

Comment: what I want to know is how exactly do compilers (gcc in particular) generate bytecode(?) from ASM

Comment: I have added your statement as an Edit to the question itself. Somebody might find it useful. :)

Comment: This is too broad, IMO. You're asking how a compiler backend works?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: presumably he means "Machine Code"

Comment: Are you asking how a compiler works?  There are entire college courses dedicated solely to the study of compilers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler

Comment: The original question was too vague. Subsequent edits have added detail to it which is clearly based on guesswork. It now *looks* like the question is about the assembler, but originally, this was not the case. The question is really too vague to be answered.

Comment: @user1233963 - You ought to clarify - Do you agree with the edits done by others? Do you really want to know about the assembler?

Comment: BTW, Assembly is another language, not machine code.

Comment: @Sdra I've always found assembly to be a highly ambiguous and context-sensitive term.  Arguably, Assembly is either a set of languages, or a context-sensitive alias for a particular member of that set.  Stating what architecture the assembly language is associated with is more precise; even then, there might be multiple assembly languages that can generate machine code for that architecture.  Normally, being pedantic about this is unnecessary, but since we don't know what the op's target architecture is..

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy: Very true! However my comment was intended to underline the fact that there has been some confusion between question, comments and question-edits. The original meaning of the question was not about how an assembler works, but how a compiler works (just read comment n. 3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assembler is a separate utility.  You can find more information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler

The source code is part of the binutils package.  You can find it here: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/

Comment: I was unable to find it's source code ( is it not open source? ). Please post a link of it if possible

Answer (score 9):

To answer this question one would need books, not just a few lines.

The **extremely** short version is:

A compiler is divided in 2 parts:

1. a Front-end that translates a specific language (like C) into a syntax-tree (generic way to represent a program)
2. and a Back-end which translates the syntax-tree into machine specific (X86, ARM, ...) code.

There are several steps involved:

1. Lexical analysis (converting keywords like "switch" into codes)
2. Syntax analysis (converting from the previous step into a syntax-tree)
3. Code optimization (modifies the syntax-tree to improve performance)
4. Code generation (generates machine code from the syntax-tree)
5. Linking (combines together more execution units into one binary file)

Googling around can give you more detailed info.

Comment: These is indeed an overview of steps a compiler does to translate one language (C++) into another (assembly code for a specific machine). If you want to learn more about it, I could suggest you read _[The Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition) - A very famous book on Compilers Design_

Comment: A very nice overview if I ever read one. It could use a part #3: Profit.